# running py3to2 using windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, command, file-conversion

I've tried my best for an hour, but I just don't understand code lingo well enough to get py3to2 to work.  I have a script written in Python 3 that I want to convert to 2.  Downloaded and unzipped py3to2 from here: 
https://bitbucket.org/amentajo/lib3to2/overview

This is all the read me says about running it:

## Usage

Run "./3to2" to convert stdin ("-"), files or directories given as
arguments.  By default, the tool outputs a unified diff-formatted patch on
standard output and a "what was changed" summary on standard error, but the
"-w" option can be given to write back converted files, creating
".bak"-named backup files.

If you are root, you can also install with "./setup.py build" and
"./setup.py install" ("make install" does this for you).

Do I need to run Python?  Command line?  I'm lost.  Has anyone done this?  Thanks.

Comment: Command line. Something like  `C:\Path\to\python.exe C:\path\to\3to2 -w myfiles`.

Comment: @ThomasK I moved the contents of the zip file that I downloaded from the bitbucket site into my Python 32 folder, so the path should be C:\Python32\Py3to2.  Therefore I put this in the command line: C:\Python32\Py3to2\3to2 -w (myFileName).  This gets an error in command line, saying this is an unrecognizable command.   (myFileName) is a file in my Python32 folder.  Do I need to designate this somehow?

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, but you might need to use `python` or `C:\Python32\python.exe` at the start of the command.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know how to use pip?

Just type in `C:/[Enter your python folder]/Scripts/pip install 3to2`

Go to the Scripts folder in the Python folder and rename `3to2` to `3to2.py`

Then, type in `C:/[Enter python folder again]/python.exe C:/[Enter python folder]/Scripts/3to2.py -w Path/To/The/Python/File`

Comment: I added a `-w` to the command. Entering it will actually write out the changes to the file